Unable to bind data in Ag-Grid SSRM v30.2.0
I'm using 30.2 version of Ag-Grid for ClientSide and ServerSide rendering
"ag-grid-angular": "30.2.0",
"ag-grid-community": "30.2.0",
"ag-grid-enterprise": "30.2.0",

I'm facing issue only with Serverside model
  <custom-ag-grid
    #summaryGrid
    *ngIf="summary"
    [columns]="summary.header"
    [rows]="summary.rows"
    [defaultColDef]="summary.defaultColDef"
    [masterDetail]="true"
    [rowModelType]="'serverSide'"
    [detailCellRendererParams]="summary.gridDetail"
    [pageSize]="20"
    [autoHeight]="false"
    [autoWidth]="false"
    [module]="'summary'"
    [serverSideDataSource]="dataSource()"
    ></custom-ag-grid>

summary.component.ts
 dataSource(): any {
    return {
      // multiple times getRows method called in v31
      getRows: (params: any) => {
        this.filter.startRow = params.request.startRow;
        this.filter.endRow = params.request.endRow;
        this.addSubscription(
          this.summary.querySummary(this.filter).subscribe((resp: any) => {
            this.summary.rows = resp.data;
            params.success({ rowData: resp.data, rowCount: resp.totalCount });
          })
        );
      },
    };
  }

CustomAgrid.component.ts
export class CustomAgGrid implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  public onGridReady(params: any): void {
    this.params = params;
    if (this.rowModelType == 'serverSide') {
      this.params.api.setServerSideDatasource(this.serverSideDataSource);
    }
}

CustomAgrid.component.html
First row Id - {{rows[0]?.id}}<br>
Last row Id - {{rows[19]?.id}}

<ag-grid-angular
  [id]="prefixId + id"
  [attr.data-cy]="datacy"
  [class]="wrapperClass"
  [columnDefs]="rows.length > 0 ? columns : []"
  [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
  [headerHeight]="height"
  [rowData]="rows"
  [rowClass]="rowClass"
  [rowClassRules]="rowClassRules"
  [rowHeight]="rowHeight"
  [animateRows]="true"
  [masterDetail]="masterDetail"
  [detailRowAutoHeight]="true"
  [alwaysShowHorizontalScroll]="true"
  [alwaysShowVerticalScroll]="true"
  [detailCellRendererParams]="detailCellRendererParams"
  [isExternalFilterPresent]="isExternalFilterPresent.bind(this)"
  [doesExternalFilterPass]="doesExternalFilterPass.bind(this)"
  [domLayout]="domLayout"
  [components]="frameworkComponents"
  [pagination]="pageSize !== false"
  [paginationPageSize]="pageSize"
  [maxBlocksInCache]="200"
  [rowModelType]="rowModelType"
  [cacheBlockSize]="rowModelType == 'serverSide' ? pageSize: null"
  [paginationAutoPageSize]="autoPageSize"
  [tooltipShowDelay]="500"
  (rowClicked)="onRowClicked($event)"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
  (firstDataRendered)="onFirstDataRendered($event)"
  [gridOptions]="gridOptions"></ag-grid-angular>

Output

But data is not getting binded to Ag-Grid. Any config missing?
